# getpass.getuser / os.environ['username'] returns computer name and not username

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, windows-services, getpass

I made a service with python which will call this app made with pyinstaller using subprocess.popen. It makes a call to getpass.getuser() but instead of the username it returns the computer-name.

I've tried getpass.getuser() / os.environ['username'] / win32api.GetUserName()
but all return *Computer-Name* and not *username*.

BTW here, computer name refers to "DESKTOP-Q..." and username is the username of the person logged in ( here "wasim" )

Any method to get the username and not the computer-name ?

Comment: Does the code making the calls that presumably fail run as a Windows NT service, i.e. does it run under a service context (as opposed to an interactive user session)?

Comment: it runs as a service from win32serviceutil !

Comment: So then, there's no *"person logged in"*. See [Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services) to learn, how the system you are trying to use works.

Comment: okay ! i get some stuff ! ok, then is there any way to run a program as a service / i just want that program to be never closed + even if it closes then it should restart ! i.e windows restart / freshboot ! i figured out services are the way to do it ! is there any other way ? or can i solve this problem of elevated user ??

Comment: A service can be configured to start when the system boots. It can also be configured to restarted when it fails. It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve, that requires to get the user name of a user logged into an interactive session. But if you need that, you're going to have to run a process in that interactive session. That process can communicate with the service.

Comment: @IInspectable, it's like a notification server running on the client machine ! which needs to register itself to the main server with the user's username and it's IP Add, hence i need the username. Well and you mean the process should be started by the user right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it ! not by using getpass but by using psutil.
so the service by default runs under LOCAL SYSTEM account, which means it's running in a completely different environment.
my situation required me to have the service running in LOCAL SYSTEM account and not the user's account as the user of the system may change ( from AD ).
to achieve this i did...

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.users()[0].name
```

*psutil.users()* returns a list of logged in users